# Can I add titles to locations for the directions url for maps.google.com?

Tags: android, google-maps, url, maps, directions

I'm currently asking for directions using the following url:
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.39384,-71.14494&daddr=48.3938453,-75.3423

This works great and the directions come through fine. Unfortunately the directions are between "Unknown Road" and "Unknown Road". This is of course because I'm using lat/lon coordinates.

I was wondering if there was a way that I could add titles to the url so that the directions wouldn't change, but the start and end points would be labeled correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add titles by wrapping a string in parenthesis after the location. So an example URL would be:

[https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=37.7793,-122.4192 (My City)&daddr=38.555556,-121.468889 (Granny's City)](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=37.7793,-122.4192%20%28My%20City%29&daddr=38.555556,-121.468889%20%28Granny%27s%20City%29)

You can see that the webpage title and the driving directions refer to the lat/long locations as whatever you put in the parenthesis after them.

**EDIT**: Looks like 4 years after my original answer above, Google changed this behavior, and unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. It is being left here for historical record.

Comment: This does work on the web. But unfortunately it does not work on android.

Comment: By android I mean the Android Google Maps application.

Comment: @atreat You're correct, the Google Maps application for Android doesn't support this. If you're providing this URL in a link on a webpage, unfortunately there isn't much you can do. If you're providing this link in an Android application, then you have more control by building a MapActivity that handles what you want.

Comment: @AndersLindén Looks like 4 years after my original answer, Google changed this behavior, and unfortunately it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @AndersLindén: I went ahead and edited my answer with this note. This is preferable to removing the answer entirely, since the question and answer are relevant for the time they were asked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers

**A bit more explanation:**

As far as i know it's not possible to add labels to directions generated with the normal google maps, but by using the google maps api it's possible to place custom markers with custom labels or even icons on the map. You can try adding markers next to your route by editing the url as explained on aforementioned page, and if you feel like it could make an application that does that for you.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your post to explain your findings, instead of just dropping a link? The latter is almost completely unhelpful.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. The idea seems like a good one to me. I'll see what it takes to put in in place.